# How to set different size for selectionIndicatorImage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In file **AppDelegate** I tried to manage my `tabBar`.

```
//Customize tabBar
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = theme.tabBarBackground
UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = //need to generate image
```

On stackoverflow I found extension for `UIImage`:

```
public extension UIImage {
    public convenience init?(color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

With this extension I can use method: `UIImage(color: <#T##UIColor#>, size: <#T##CGSize#>)`

So I need to manage CGSize. For that I need to get tabBar in app delegate.

How I can get in and will it be correct to manage tab bar in appdelegate file in viewWillAppear?

P.S. i'm just learning :p

Comment: "will it be correct to manage tab bar in appdelegate file in viewWillAppear?" No, because an app delegate is not a view controller so it has no `viewWillAppear`. Why not do this in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, if the tab bar controller is your root view controller...?

Comment: oh ok! thx. So is it the best way to make selectionIndicatorImage for different sizes or someone make it another way?

Comment: I can't answer a 'best way" question; "best" is a moral judgment. Creating a selection indicator image in code is perfectly normal.